# How do I automatically change the background image of body?

Tags: 7, theming

How do I automatically change the background image of body, when I click on a menu link?

I want to obtain the same effect shown in the [Drupal Design Camp Boston 2011](http://boston2011.design4drupal.org/) site.

Comment: Like to note that the site, the images are random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that is added directly to the page and is not part of a seperate script.

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function () { $('body').css( 'background-image', 'url("/sites/default/files/palm1.jpg")' ) });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function () { $('body').css( 'background-color', '#2a2f1d' ) });
//--><!]]>
```

The place where you want do this is inside your theme's template.php file under the function `MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)`

then add something like

```
$script_bg_img = "jQuery(document).ready(function () { $('body').css( 'background-image', `url('/sites/default/files/palm1.jpg')` ) });"
drupal_add_js($script_bg_img);
```

or put the javascript in a separate file, then add
   `drupal_add_js(PATH_TO_FILE . '/FILENAME');`